# Where is the Turian General Oraka?

Tags: mass-effect-3

For the quest "Aria: Blue Suns" I'm supposed to deal with the Turian general Oraka, but I'm having a hard time finding the general as the journal offers no hint where the General could be.

Where on the Citadel is General Oraka?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Septimus Oraka can be found on the Presidium Commons level sitting on a bench.

Here is his exact location (right by my character cursor):

[image]